# Trouble Debugging SelectionSort Method

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

So I noticed when I test this code:

```
public class SelectionSort{

    public static void sorted(int[] array){

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            int key = array[i];
            int index = i;

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[i]) {
                key = array[j];
                index = j;
                }
            }

            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    //test function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{4,3,6,7,1};
        sorted(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

I get the output: {3,1,4,6,7} which is obviously not sorted. But when I change the inner loop counter from `for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)` to `for(int j = 1; j < array.length; j++)` I get the proper output of {1,3,4,6,7}. Curious why this is logically happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: First of all I don't think SO is a good place for this kind of questions (could be wrong tho). Anyway, it might be worth checking out this algorithms description on something like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation). Both of your versions are incorrect/suboptimal

Comment: Play your code by hand, you'll get insight.

Comment: It makes sense that the inner loop should loop starting from (j = i + 1) but I tried retracing my code with the bug I have (j = 0) and I can't understand why that output is being given with the two numbers unsorted.

Comment: Do you **understand** how selection sort works (conceptually)? Because from there it should be fairly easy to see why having the second loop start from the left-most (or 2nd-from-left) element wouldn't work. The exact output you're getting should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is,
From a single iteration of the outer loop it will bring the maximum element in  the array to the end of the array.

So from the next iteration, you can skip the last element off the array

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length  - i; j++)
```

But you need to keep checking the first element with it's nearest.